# A Governing Differential Equation for the Heat Loss of Coffee and Cream?

Tags: thermodynamics

Here's the problem statement: If you want your coffee hottest, do you add cream immediately or 30 minutes later? (Coffee = 90C and 12 oz., Cream = 15C and 1 oz.)

I'm fairly confident that the answer is to add the cream immediately. I have arguments based on the mechanisms of heat transfer, but I'm having trouble devising a governing differential equation related to the rate of heat loss and specific heat. This, I'm told, is essential for a solution. However, given that I've never taken differential equations I'm not really sure how to proceed...

As I understand it, adding the cream would decrease the specific heat overall, but increase the rate of heat transfer due to the increased mass of the cream. I imagine that the equation should look something like this, but I'm really not sure: dQ/dt=cm(dT/dt)

Can anyone help me quantify this relation mathematically?

Comment: I don't make coffee myself. So please tell me, why would you add cream 30 mins later. Wouldn't the coffee cool down by then? Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I guess you're keeping the cream at 15C for the 30 minutes if you're waiting that time?

Comment: I think the reasoning is that you are in transit and are cannot drink it right away. And yes, I think the cream temperature can be considered constant.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm fairly confident that the answer is to add the cream immediately.

This is an old classroom and examination problem and kind of a trick question as a class' opinion invariably breaks about 50/50, with regards to which method delivers the hottest coffee!

To solve it we make some simple assumptions, **firstly** that the cooling of the coffee, with or without immediate addition of the cream, follows [Newton's cooling law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Heat_transfer_version_of_the_law):

$$\frac{dQ}{dt}=hA(T-T_0)$$
Where $Q$ is heat energy, $t$ is time, $h$ the heat transfer coefficient, $A$ the total surface area exposed to ambient air, $T$ the temperature of the coffee and $T_0$ the temperature of the ambient air.

In an infinitesimal time interval $dt$ the coffee loses heat acc.:

$$dQ=-mcdT$$

With $m$ the mass of the coffee and $c$ its specific heat capacity (the negative sign is needed because $dT<0$).

Substituting gives us:

$$-mc\frac{dT}{dt}=hA(T-T_0)$$
Integration between $T_1, t=0$ and $T_2, t$ gives us:

$$\ln\frac{T_2-T_0}{T_1-T_0}=-\frac{hA}{mc}t \tag1$$

From which $T_2$ can be calculated.

The **second** assumption is a heat balance. When we add the cream to the coffee the temperature becomes $T_3$ and:

$$(m+m_c)cT_3=mcT+m_ccT_c$$
Where $T_3$ is the temperature after addition of the cream,  $T$ is the temperature of the coffee before addition of the cream, $T_c$ the temperature of the cream, $m_c$ the mass of the cream and $c$ the specific heat capacity of *both* cream *and* coffee, so that $c$ drops out:
$$(m+m_c)T_3=mT+m_cT_c \tag2$$
This allows to calculate $T_3$.

To determine which path leads to the hottest coffee:

1. Calculate end temperature by assuming cream was added **at the end**. Use $Eq.1$ first, then $Eq.2$.
2. Calculate end temperature by assuming cream was added **at the start**. Use $Eq.2$ first, then $Eq.1$.

   ---

   **Note:** this answer initially stated that adding cream at the start or end of the cooling period does not affect end-temperature. That was in error and the answer has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Does radiation not play a role? I've learned reading this site that radiative cooling is more important in everyday physics than I thought earlier, but I don't really know if it is important enough here.

Comment: At relatively low temperatures radiative losses are considered negligible. I did some experiments with cooling cups of coffee and good good agreement with Newton's cooling law was found. But using Stefan Boltzmann you could add a radiative loss function to the DE, if you so wish. But I can assure you that the 'spirit' of the question is to ignore radiative loss.

Comment: So you are assuming that the specific heat of the coffee and the cream are the same? Great answer, btw. Thank you!

Comment: You could assume different $c$ values for cream and coffee and the outcome would still be the same. It's just algebraically easier that way.

Comment: @Vitruvius Yes, it turns out that $m_\text{coffee} c_\text{coffee}$ and $m_\text{cream} c_\text{cream}$, i.e. heat capacities (=specific heat capacity * mass), are what matter here, so in that sense having different specific heat capacities is no different than having different masses.

Comment: Ok, so I'm still a little confused. The coffee in both cups cools at the same rate. Given that the temperature of the cream is constant, adding before or after eventually leads to both having the same temperature (as shown by the graph). BUT, wouldn't the rate of the "creamed" coffee be affected by the increased mass of the cream?

Comment: @Vitruvius: it's pointless to try and do this 'intuitively', you really just need to do the math, using the principles offered. Or do a controlled experiment! :-)

Comment: There is an error in this answer. If $h$ and $A$ remain the same, then the rate of loss of heat energy, $dQ/dt = -hA(T-T_0)$, depends only on $T$, so the amount of heat energy lost is higher in the case where $T$ is higher. Also if you actually plug in the numbers here, you'll find out that you don't get the same result in both cases.

Comment: Adding cream at the end, the temperature of coffee after cooling is $T = T_\text{cof,0} e^{-hAt/(m_\text{cof}c)}$ and the final temperature is $T_\text{final} = (m_\text{cof} T_\text{cof,0} e^{-hAt/(m_\text{cof}c)} + m_\text{cr} T_\text{cr,0})/(m_\text{cof}+m_\text{cr})$.

Comment: Adding cream in the beginning, the temperature after that is $T = (m_\text{cof} T_\text{cof,0} + m_\text{cr} T_\text{cr,0})/(m_\text{cof}+m_\text{cr})$, and the temperature after cooling is $T_\text{final} = (m_\text{cof} T_\text{cof,0} + m_\text{cr} T_\text{cr,0})/(m_\text{cof}+m_\text{cr}) \times e^{-hAt/((m_\text{cof}+m_\text{cr})c)}$. These are not equivalent.

Comment: Here I was using $0$ as the ambient temperature to simplify equations.

Comment: Ok. Give me some time to check your solutions. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @JiK: you are in fact correct. Both temperature paths do not lead to the exact same end-temperature. I must be remembering the problem wrongly or remembering a related but different problem. The answer has now been edited accordingly. Thanks for your effective proof-reading! ;-)